# Trouble with stylesheets in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, stylesheet, halo

For the life of me, I can't get stylesheets to work... Something having to do with the namespaces and the way I am setting them.  So here is my code:

```
<mx:Style>
  @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo";
  mx|DataGrid {
   headerColors: #0066cc, #00ffff;
   borderThickness: 7;
   borderColor: #00ff33;
  }
 </mx:Style>

<mx:DataGrid 
  styleName="myGridStyle"
  wordWrap="true"  
  id="people" 
  width="500" 
  height="350" 
  dataProvider="{dataArr}" 
  editable = "false" 
  itemClick="itemClickEvent(event);" sortableColumns="true"  
  rollOverColor="0xffffff"
  >
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried it many different ways and it seems to work for others in tutorials I have done.

Comment: Are you using a Beta build? Is your project using the Halo theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace has recently changed from:

`@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo";`

to

`@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";`

`mx` instead of `halo`.

Let me know if that fixes it.

Lance

Answer (score 0):

try to remove "styleName="myGridStyle"" in your datagrid declaration